# Feature not applied to public My Site profile

Tags: my-site, feature-stapling

I've written and deployed a feature for my company's My Site - all it does is replace the default Top Navigation Control with one I've modified to include a link back to our main SharePoint application.

So I've installed and enabled the feature on the Site Collection hosting our My Site and I've programatically set all existing personal sites to incorporate the feature via Powershell and that all works fine - all parts of the My Site contain a link back to the portal home. When I create a new My Site however the feature is only "stapled" for the "public" sites, e.g. My Newsfeed and My Profile but not My Content.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've only activated your feature on the my site host, not the personal sites. The "My Newsfeed" and "My Profile" pages reside on the my site host, whereas the "My Content" resides on the personal site (my site).
To staple your feature to every *new* personal site, you need to staple it to the following template: SPSPERS#0